# I want to make a helper and template to dynamically generate a view for a collection of active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This may sound strange, but none the less I want to learn how to do it and I need some help getting there. I'm not sure how to approach this. I'm hoping to get some dev love on this.... Let me explain by giving an example. (Btw thank you---you are awesome!)

Instead of this in my view:

```
<table>
  @users.map do |user|
   ...
</table>
```

I want to extract it away into a helper that I can reuse for other collections.

So I want to say instead:

```
@users.to_table({
  template: "simple_template",
  header: ["Full Name","Email"],
  column: ["name", "email"]
})
```

So in my application_helper I have something like this: (pseudo-ish code)

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def to_table *args
    load args.template

    self.map do |j|
      args.header do |header|
        j.header
      end
      args.column do |column|
        j.column
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea how to wire this up. (helper or table template) Definitely an order of magnitude above my current skill level. Need some serious direction.. I'm asking this because I feel like I hit a learning plateau and need help busting through to something more challenging (hence this question)... Hope it's clear, if not ask for clarification. Thanks for reading... Thanks for helping! =)

Comment: Well to start `args.template` would be wrong. instead I would accept a `Hash` rather than use the splat `*` e.g. `def to_table(options={})` then use `Hash` style `args[:template]`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah I get that... What else can you suggest? No rush... Take your time.... If you're feeling inclined an answer with some code examples would be awesome... Maybe you can be point to blog post..?? Can't seem to find what I'm asking for...

Answer (score 1):

Not guaranteeing this will work it is just to show the syntax issues:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def to_table(options={})
    load options[:template]
    self.map do |j|
      Hash[
        args[:headers].zip(args[:columns].map{ |column| j.send(column) }
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Not Sure about the load part I think this should be handled outside of the relation as it is a `view` issue and has nothing to do with the `ActiveRecord::Relation` but this method will return an `Array` of `Hash`es like

```
[{"Full Name" => "USER 1 Name", "Email" => "USER1@email.com},{"Full Name" => "USER 2 Name", "Email" => "USER2@email.com"}]
```

In your current method `args` which is an array now based on the `*` will not respond to things like `template` or `column`. Like I said I have never really tried to implement anything in this way but the syntax change might get you headed in the right direction. Also handling should be put in place for when `template` is not passed or `headers.count != columns.count`.

Best bet is probably something like this

```
<%= render "template", obj: @user.to_table(headers: ["Full Name","Email"],columns: ["name", "email"]) %>
```

in _template.rb

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <% obj.first.keys.each do |header|
       <th><%= header %></th>
     <% end %>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <% obj.each do |row|
    <tr>
       <% row.values.each do |cell| %>
         <td><%= cell %></td>
       <% end %>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Although if I had more time to think there are probably far simpler implementations of this maybe something like

```
<%= render 'template', locals:{collection: @users, headers: ["Full Name","Email"], columns: ["name", "Email"]} %>
```

**UPDATE** 
I think making a view helper might be better in this instance like this

```
def make_table(collection,options={})
  content_tag(:table,options[:table_options]) do 
    content_tag(:thead) do 
      content_tag(:tr) do
        options[:headers].map do |header,header_options| 
          content_tag(:th,header,header_options,false)
        end.join.html_safe
      end
    end
    content_tag(:tbody,options[:body_options]) do 
      collection.map do |obj|
        content_tag(:tr,options[:row_options]) do
          options[:columns].map do |column,cell_options|
            content_tag(:td,obj.public_send(column),cell_options,false) 
          end.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

call as

```
<%= make_table(@users,columns:{name:{class: "name"},email:{}},headers:{"Full Name"=>{class:"name_header"},"Email"=>{}}) %>
```

or without formatting

```
<%= make_table(@users,columns:[:name,:email],headers:["Full Name","Email"]) %>
```

This method requires an object collection and will accept the following through the `options` `Hash`

```
 :table_options as a Hash to pass to the content tag for formatting the table
 :headers as an Array or Hash (for formatting header rows)
 :body_options as a Hash to pass to the content tag for formatting the table body
 :row_options as a Hash to pass to the content tag for formatting the rows
 :columns as an Array or Hash (for formatting the individual cells)
```

You can place this method in helpers/application_helper.rb and you will have access to it throughout the application. **Although I have not fully vetted this method and it is currently more conceptual than anything else.**

Comment: Yeah that code is supposed to be pseudoish style.. Pretty sure `load` is not the correct way to go.. How about a template..? I remember seeing something about creating a template for email... just unclear on how to go about it...

Comment: Yea I like this: " Also handling should be put in place for when template is not passed or headers.count != columns.count." So that by default you can just say `@users.to_table` and get a view of something simple.. options being of course optional..

Comment: This is really interesting. Thanks for your answer.. When you have more time.. Feel free to add to it ... I will leave the question open for now to see what others suggest.. +1 for the answer.. Thanks dude!

Comment: @f1f5 I have updated my answer with a solution I think would work much better for this. I still did not put in handling for headers.count != columns.count. I think this is something you can work out or make sure you use it appropriately.

Comment: Hey thanks for this.. I'm going to try this out when I have some time and let you know how it goes. Thanks =)